# configuring Rails on IIS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iis

We are planning to take a virtual dedicated server where we can host our .NET , PHP and rails application together .  Since we need to host .NET webapps , linux is out of question . I have configured PHP on IIS , but was wondering if it is possible to configure rails with IIS . 
 
We want to avoid another webserver running just for rails .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've set it up on IIS7 using the tools available at http://roriis.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a blog post for IIS 6 with Rails 3 [here](http://blog.trekforth.com/2011/06/installing-spree-on-windows-2003-server.html) in case anyone else is looking for that kind of configuration and finds this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft ISA server, it can act as a reverse proxy to Mongrel cluster.  There is also a plugin called [IIRF](http://iirf.codeplex.com/) that works to achieve the same goals in standard IIS.