# Rails3 on Windows

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails-3

I am about to start a new site which needs to reside on a Windows server.
I have done Ruby development in the past and am therefore naturally very keen on using Rails for this project.

Is this a safe option as on Linux/Mac or should I stick to .NET as this is the native choice for the platform?

Also, what about IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine, you should be able to use more or less the same kind of deployment scenario as on unix, only problem you might run into is installing gems that contains native (C most of the time) code.

Comment: Under IIS will be hard (if possible), mongrel + mongrel_service with apache or nginx as loadbalancer

Comment: And this setup would be able to run in paralell with an additional website on the same machine which would be running under IIS?

Comment: Well, you won't be able to run both iis and something else on the same port, something like this might work for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1871711/configuring-rails-on-iis